# Match RegEx against tag with embedded self-closing tag

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to find a tag if used as a self-closing tag.  However, I want to ignore any self-closing tags that might be embedded in the innerHtml; if not used in a self-closing way.

Here's an example of the tag used in a self-closing way:

> `This is a test <a id="anchor1" />.`

Here's an example of the tag when not used in a self-closing way, which I want to include:

> `This is a separate test <a id="anchor2"><img src="file.png"/></a>.`

Here's the regular expression I'm trying to use, which is picking up both:

```
(?i)<a.*[^<]?/>
```

Any suggestions about why this isn't working?

Comment: 1) `.*` - matches any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns, 2) `[^<]?` matches only 1 or 0 chars other than `<`. Use `(?i)<a(?:\s[^<]*)?/>`

Comment: That works!  Thanks!